# PendingIntent, BroadcastReceiver, IBinder что для чего используют в практике?

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, pendingintent

`PendingIntent`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `IBinder` все это используют для связи активностей и сервисов, в некоторых функционалах эти штуки позволяют выполнять одни и те же задачи, а в некоторых нет, что для чего выбирают?

Допустим есть конкретный пример, запущен `ForegroundService` и он отправляет сообщения в `Activity`, нужно чтоб сообщения принимались `Activity` даже после его удаления и перезагрузки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intent - это "сообщение", которое шлет ваше приложение куда то "в эфир", не имея точного адресата, а имея свое уникальное "имя". Его получат все в системе, кто подписан на получение сообщений с таким "именем".
PendingIntent отличается от Intent тем, что позволяет выполнять действия получателем "сообщения" с правами приложения, которое отправило этот интент. Обычный интент выполняется с правами "принимающего" приложения.

BroadcastReceiver - приемник посланных кем то интент-сообщений. В нем подписываются на прослушивание "эфира" и перехватывают интересующие "сообщения"-интенты по их "именам".

Два этих инструмента работают в паре. Как нетрудно заметить, в этой схеме нет четкой привязки между отправителем и приемником, получить и перехватить "сообщение" может любое приложение в системе. Связь открытая и полностью "развязанная" - приемник и получатель ничего не знают друг о друге, кроме "имени"-интента.

IBinder - интерфейс обратного вызова для связи сервиса и приложения. Здесь абсолютная закрытая связь между разными частями одной программы, посылаемые через интерфейс данные получат только там, где находится метод обратного вызова (`onBind()`)именно реализованного в "отправляющей" стороне интерфейса. Данные части "жестко" связаны и не могут работать одна без другой.

Если слать интенты, то ресивер, на них подписанный, сработает и при незапущенном в данный момент приложении (активити) при условии, если приложение подписывалось на эти интенты через манифест, соответственно активити будет запущена.

PS:Написав "после его удаления" вы имеете ввиду, что активити в данный момент не запущена? если приложение, подписанное на интент было деинсталлировано (как можно понимать "удалить"), то оно, естественно, не установится заново, чтобы принять отправленый интент, он просто уйдет "в никуда", если на него нет других подписчиков (ресиверов).